# update input fields after append

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on an intranet web form. The form allows users to create "slideshows" (div field containing input fields - drop-down, textboxes, and buttons). Users can dynamically chose to add as many slideshows as they want. Users can also change the slideshow "type" (drop-down, which hides some input fields).

The way I am adding div fields is by calling a function (located in a different file). The function just appends the slideshow with unique IDs/Names for each field.
I am also using jQuery UI to make these slideshows sortable. Everything works fine except for when I need to update certain input values (or hide input fields).

I need to fix two things:

- Update an input field when the slideshows are sorted/re-ordered.
- hide certain elements depending on the "type" drop-down

I know I can do that by using

```
$('.type').change(function () { // hide elements });
$( "#main" ).sortable({ update: function() { // update elements}});
```

but it seems jQuery doesn't allow us to easily access fields after appending.

I have searched online for possible solutions (that use "on click" events), but could not get anything to work. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Could an example of the resulting `html` be posted? Thanks.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the used code at [http://pastebin.com/KJZDWLHe](http://pastebin.com/KJZDWLHe)

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Please see post. May partially meet 2nd listed requirement, tried with `type=text` as well. Appeared to work. However, would prefer to pass the jquery `method`, in the post's instance, `.hide()` as a variable, for example `sortInput(type, .hide()){};`, tried a few ways, no success; will continue trying options to achieve that feature. Should be able to select and perhaps meet the 1st listed requirement as well, with the piece, by modifying it to include other methods. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated)

```
    function sortInput(el, type, action, val) {
      /* `el` : all `input` elements, or, `el#id`, `el.class`, `el[attr]` as `jquery` `object` */
      var inputs = $(el);
      /* `type` of `$(el)`, i.e.g., `text`, `submit`, `hidden`, etc.  */
      var type = (type || undefined); 
      /* if no `newVal` prodided, return `$(this).val() as `default`  */
      var val = val || $(this).val();
      /* `action` to call for `$(el)`, `hide` calls jsquery `.hide()`, `val` calls jquery `.val()` with provided `val` parameter */
      $.fn.actions = (action === "hide"
             ? function() {return this.hide()} 
             : (action === "val" ? function() {return this.val(val)} : null)
             ); 
      /* jquery `.filter()` `$(el)`'s by provided `type` */
      return $(inputs).filter(function() {
      /* `return` `$(el)`, `filter()`'ed by `type`, call `$.fn.actions()` provided with `action` parameter  */
        return $(this).attr("type") === type}).actions()
    };
    /* call `sortInput()`, `.filter()` `type` `submit`, call jquery `.hide()` */
    sortInput("input", "submit", "hide");
    /* call `sortInput()`, `.filter()` `type` `text`, call jquery `.val()`, with `val` ("newVal") provided parameter */
    sortInput("input", "text", "val", "newVal");
```

Try this (untested)

```
$(".type").on("change", "input", function (e) {
  console.log(e.target); return sortInput("input", "submit", "hide"); 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I just wanted to say Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it. I am just trying to understand this code - could you please explain it? How can I call the function on drop down change (for my first requirement)?
`$('.type').change(function () { sortInput() });`
would not work as it is not triggered on "appended div".